# Can I use a Talent without initation?

Tags: skills, wurm

I'm currently creating my first character for a [*Würm*](https://www.nocturnal-media.com/new-page-1-1) game. At character creation you choose a tribe (which determines starting skills) and Strengths.

My character is a **Long Man** (Aurignacian culture) with the Strength **Inspiration of the Rocks**. Inspiration of the Rocks gives me a bonus 1d6 to tests related to painting, engraving, or sculpting.

However, members of the Aurignacian culture don't start with any kind of art skills (in fact, no one does). It's clear to me that I can learn arts later through initiation or purchase one at start-up by also taking a Weakness.

Assuming I don't, is Inspiration of the Rocks useless until later on? Or can I attempt tasks without first "learning" them (similar to untrained checks from other games)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### No.

You cannot use a Talent or Secret Skill without being initiated. This is mentioned in-passing several different places in the book. The most direct is in the character creation section (pg.30) which says:

> Talents and Secret Skills represent fields of knowledge that the characters can only use after initation.

Becoming initiated is a significant part of gameplay. Characters don't simply learn Talents mechanically, they must earn the respect of the spirits and of their clan. Becoming eligible to learn a Talent (or Secret Skill) is often either explicitly the beginning of a quest, or a sub-plot.

### But You Missed Something

There are ways to start the game with a single Talent. Both are in the text of page 30.

A character may start play with a weakness. If they do, they may select a Talent or Secret Skill at character creation.

Additionally, the GM may choose to give players an initial Talent or Secret Skill. The text provides numerous instances where that may be a good idea.